# VueJS 2.x Where should I declare variables not used in data-binding?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

As the title reads, should I declare **all** my variables in `data`? Or only the ones used for data-binding?

```js
<script>
    var somethingElse = '';    //should this be declared here?
    export default {
    data () {
        return {
            something: '',     //this var will be used in data-binding
            somethingElse: ''  //or here?

        }
    }

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you come from other libs/frameworks, where there's difference in instance variables and **state**. Where changing instance variables doesn't trigger re-renders, but changing the state might.

In Vue you don't have to worry about that. You can have everything in `data`, and Vue will only re-render if you change something that is actually used anywhere that matters (e.g. the template).

```js
<script>
    export default {
    data () {
        return {
            something: '',     
            somethingElse: '' // you can declare it here, it's the usual way
        }
    }

...
```

On the other hand, you could declare the variable outside, but if you do:

```js
<script>
    var somethingElse = ''; // this will be a singleton. Generally used for constants
    export default {
    data () {
        return {
            something: '',     //this var will be used in data-binding
        }
    }

...
```

Then `somethingElse` will be shared among all instances of this component. It will be sort of a singleton value for all of them: if you change in one, it will change for all instances at the same time. (And it won't be reactive, meaning a change to `somethingElse` won't trigger a re-render anywhere.)